# Utilizando Hibernate para gerar tabelas com h2

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, jpa

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual decidi utilizar o h2 como banco de dados embarcado. É a primeira vez que estou utilizando esse tipo de banco de dados e estou tendo problemas para  gerar as tabelas pelo hibernate.

meu **hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:../blcul</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="domain.Cliente" />  
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Minha classe **HibernateUtils** (apenas teste) :

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static Configuration configurantion;

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public static void initConfiguration() {
    try {
        configurantion = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        sb.applySettings(configurantion.getProperties());
        StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();
        sessionFactory = configurantion
                .buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed" + e);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}
}
```

e no meu Frame eu inicializo o hibernate dessa maneira :

```
public Frame() {
    HibernateUtil.initConfiguration();
    createCardLayout();
    setProperties();
}
```

Essa classe Cliente que criei é apenas uma entidade que estou usando para testar

```
/**
  * @author Anderson
  * @date 13/04/2014
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTE")
public class Cliente {

private Long id;

private String nome;

/**
 * Construtor
 */
public Cliente() {
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the nome
 */
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

/**
 * @param nome the nome to set
 */
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
}
```

Como o show sql esta habilidado quando as configurações do hibernate são executadas o seguinte sql é mostrado no console :

```
drop table CLIENTE if exists
create table CLIENTE (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    nome varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)
```

Não apresenta nenhuma exceção. Quando olho no console do h2, nenhuma tabela foi criada :

[image]
Não estou enxergando onde está o problema. As configurações do hibernate eu peguei da documentação no próprio site do h2.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a chave hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto e não hbm2ddl.auto.

Comment: Ele reclamou que o projeto não estava criando as tabelas. A solução do problema dele é a configuração errada que eles estava utilizando. Isso não seria uma resposta?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @uaiHebert. Funcionou. Dado que o hibernate é uma implementação de JPA, utilizar a propriedade como "hmb2ddl.auto" não deveria funcionar também? Essa propriedade não é prevista na especificação?

Comment: Se não me engano, só na versão 2.2 do JPA que essa configuração passou a fazer parte da especificação. Se você usar essa configuração com o eclipseLink ela não funcionará. [=

Comment: @Anderson Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de votar e marcá-la como resposta correta (o pequeno checkmark embaixo dos votos)

Comment: @uaiHebert O que esa chave faz? Sou meio (muito... bastante) ignorante quanto ao Hibernate.

Comment: Serve para controlar o relacionamento entre banco e seu esquema de banco de dados. Você tem as seguintes opções: não faz nada (default), valide (valida todo o banco de dados comparando ao esquema, ideal para produção), faça drop das tabelas e crie tudo novamente, atualize o banco de dados com o esquema atual (imagine que vc adicionou uma coluna), etc.